# jQuery if href attr

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this html structure:

```
<ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab1"><h3>Sound</h3><img class="servicesIcon" src="img/micro.png"></img></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2"><h3>Lighting</h3><img class="servicesIcon" src="img/light.png"></img></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3"><h3>Staging</h3><img class="servicesIcon" src="img/barstool.png"></img></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4"><h3>Sales</h3><img class="servicesIcon" src="img/info.png"></img></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.co.uk/" target="_BLANK"><h3>Hire Guide</h3><img class="servicesIcon" src="img/info.png"></img></a></li>
        </ul>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {



                $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
                $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
                $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

                var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
                $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
                return false;
            });
```

But what i want to do is if the 'li' is clicked that doesn't have a href of #tab then it just returns true and follows the link as normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're saying that you don't want the handler to fire for the link without a `#tab`, then just don't assign the handler to it in the first place.

```
$("ul.tabs li").slice(0,-1).click(function() {
    // and so on
```

This will assign the click handler to all but the last one.

You could also do something more like this:

```
$("ul.tabs li:not(:last)").click(function() {
    // and so on
```

or:

```
$("ul.tabs li:not(:last-child)").click(function() {
    // and so on
```

Comment: @benhowdie89: You're welcome. Just keep in mind that of the 3, you'll get the slowest performance with that one because it isn't a valid querySelectorAll selector. Really not too big of a deal though since this runs only once. :o)

Answer (score 3):

To complete `patrick dw's` list, the generic version:

```
$('ul.tabs li:has(a[href^=#tab])').click(function() {
});
```

This will only effect `li nodes` which contain an anchor with a href that begins with `#tab`

Comment: I guess I also should point out that this kind of selectors have a poor performance and you should use them wiseley. In this context, no problem!

Comment: I agree. This is one of those cases where it really isn't so bad. (That's why I deleted my comment.) Though I would strongly lean toward selectors that querySelectorAll can use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple external links you could use this:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
if(activeTab.substr(0,1) == '#'){ //if link starts with # - do fade, else treat as actual link.
  $(activeTab).fadeIn();
  return false;
}
else
  return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $(".tab_content").hide();

    var takE = $(this).attr('href'); //select the href from clicked element
    var swap = takE.replace('#',''); //strip it, if #tab1 clicked result = 'tab1'
    $('#' + swap).show(); // this will show clicked element like id="tab1"

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selectors to bind only to the links whose target starts with the string `#tab`:

```
$("ul.tabs a[href^=#tab]").click(function() {
    //...
});
```

This would require you to modify the contents of your function slightly, because the context will have changed (from the `li` to the `a`).

More at http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML as follows as the syntax is a little off :

1. You cannot have block elements inside inline elements.
2. `<img></img>` should be `<img />` and have an alt attribute even if it is blank.
3. You can change your unordered list to an ordered list to let a user know how many tabs there are. (You are already marking up the href="tab1...tab2" so there is already an order to it)

   `<ol class="tabs">
   <li><h3><a href="#tab1">Sound<img alt="" class="servicesIcon" src="img/micro.png" /></a></h3></li>
   </ol>`